# ¿Por qué al hacer scroll en ListView con imagenes se pone lento?

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un problema con un *listView*, el cual muestra una imagen, el título y la descripción. Al desplazarme por el *listView* para ver los elementos que están abajo o al subir de nuevo, el desplazamiento es lento. Quisiera saber, ¿Cómo puedo optimizar el código? o ¿Qué necesito hacer para que el desplazamiento sea normal?

*PropiedadCursorAdapter.java*

```
public class PropiedadCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context ctx;
private  Cursor miCursor;
private int layout;


private PropiedadDbAdapter dbAdapter =null;

private  class ViewHolder {

    ImageView ivCasa;
    TextView tvTitulo;
    TextView tvUbicacion;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        tvTitulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
        tvUbicacion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ubicacion);
        ivCasa = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivCasa);
    }

}

public PropiedadCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
    super(context, c);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.miCursor = c;


    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    dbAdapter = new PropiedadDbAdapter(context);
    dbAdapter.abrir();
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    int icol_ivCasa = c.getColumnIndex(C_COLUMNA_IMAGENES);
    int icol_tvTitulo = c.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_TITULO);
    int icol_tvUbicacion = c.getColumnIndex(PropiedadDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_DIRECCION);

    String stxtCasa = c.getString(icol_ivCasa);
    String stxtTitulo = c.getString(icol_tvTitulo);
    String stxUbicacion = c.getString(icol_tvUbicacion);

    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    Picasso.with(context).load(stxtCasa).into(vh.ivCasa);
    vh.tvTitulo.setText(stxtTitulo);
    vh.tvUbicacion.setText(stxUbicacion);


}

@Override
public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_propiedades, parent, false);
    vView.setTag( new ViewHolder(vView) );

    return vView;

}
  }
```

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería que pusieras un código completo para que pudiéramos reproducir el error.

Comment: Deberías aprender RecyclerView es mucho mejor y ps es el sucesor del ListView aquí te dejo un link-> http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: @marlonpya gracias, checaré el link. 
Crees que si agrego  un AsyncTask tenga un mejor rendimiento o es preferible cambiar a un recyclerView?

Comment: AsyncTask es para otra cosa.. deberías apoyarte en librerías para el manejo de imágenes cómo Picasso, Fresco ó Glide, bueno yo utilizo Glide que me parece una bendición :v.. jajaj bueno si me das un tiempo te podría dar una manito para que puedas tener un mejor control de tu código

Answer (score 1):

`Picasso` te da la posibilidad redimensionar la imagen, puedes probar a ponerle el tamaño exacto de `vh.ivCasa` y a ver que pasa ^^

```
Picasso.with(context)
.resize(600, 200) // width, height
.centerCrop()
.load(stxtCasa).into(vh.ivCasa);
```

Comment: Gracias, agregué lo siguiente :

`Picasso.with(context).load(stxtCasa).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(vh.ivCasa);`

Y me funcionó.

Comment: @IvonneLopez Si esta fue es la solución a tu problema, marcala como respuesta correcta

Comment: @Maguz La solución fue usar un RecyclerView, redimensionar me sirvió por un momento pero al volver a entrar a la aplicación el desplazamiento seguía siendo lento.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando instancias tu adapter:

```
public PropiedadCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
    super(context, c);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.miCursor = c;


    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    dbAdapter = new PropiedadDbAdapter(context);
    dbAdapter.abrir();
}
```

Dentro vuelves a instanciarlo, esto puede ser una causa de la lentitud que experimentas ya que siempre que se instancia, en el constructor vuelves a instanciar el adapter.

Elimina esa linea, además `dbAdapter.abrir();` no se que operación realiza pero también puede ser innecesaria:

```
public PropiedadCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
    super(context, c);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.miCursor = c;


    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
//    dbAdapter = new PropiedadDbAdapter(context);
  //  dbAdapter.abrir();
}
```

Comment: Era innecesaria, ya la eliminé pero todo sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Para tener optimizado un listView para que consuma menos memoria RAM como también no tenga problemas de memoria disponible dando una excepción.

Lo importante:

- Es que dentro del adapter personalizado sólo se use el LayoutInflater si la vista es null, o si no se reutilice esa vista. También es importante usar un ViewHolder.

Un ejemplo hipotético para darte una idea:

```
 if (convertView == null){
            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_persona, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textViewNombre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre);
            viewHolder.textViewApellido = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewApellido);
            viewHolder.textViewEdad = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEdad);
            viewHolder.thumb_persona = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_persona);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Avisame, porque acabo de probar en un ejemplo y me va súper rápido y tengo varios elementos en la lista. En mi ejemplo utilice SimpleCursorAdapter, pero no habría problema de adaptar a tu código.